# Call client to client

Tags: php, react-native, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-php

// makecall.php////

```
 $client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);
 $call = $client->calls ->create("client:123@123.comm679","client:clientid",  
            [       
                'url' => 'xxxxxxxxx/POrtal/ClientsPortal/incoming.php',  
            ]
        );
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 print($call->sid);
```

//incomming.php

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

$response = new VoiceResponse();
$response->say('Hello!');

echo $response;
```

I have fixed makecall.php in Voice Configuration myTwimlapp->Request URL and on connect function of @twilio/voice-react-native-sdk  calling the makecall.php.
I want to call from client to client using twilio  @twilio/voice-react-native-sdk in react native .  Call is initiated but disconnecting automatically on client:clientid and Call goes to 'client:123@123.comm679' but it listen recorded 'hello'. But i want client:123@123.comm679 and client:clientid talk each other.I am unable to understand from https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml.  How to handle live call between two clients.I am beginner in twillio please help.

I want to live call between two twilio clients. I am unable to understand from twilio docs how to handle the response.